# Calculating degrees of freedom for a contingency table with interactions

Tags: interaction, poisson-regression, contingency-tables, degrees-of-freedom

Below is a contingency table with residual deviance given by a Poisson regression model with a log-link. I have searched online and I believe that for the mutually exclusive model `coffee + cigar + MI` it is `(number of rows - 1) - (number of columns - 1)`. My question is how the degrees of freedoms were obtained for the interaction terms, and is there an intuitive way of understanding how to calculate the degrees of freedom?

[image]

Comment: See our posts on [interaction degrees of freedom](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interaction+degrees+freedom).

Comment: The closest thing I have found is this : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144931/degrees-of-freedom-in-anova but I don't know how it calculates the model for coffee + cigar + MI
I would get:
    (4-1) from df of coffee - 1
 + (4-1) from df of cigarettes - 1
 + 4 * (2-1) from the nested Cases 
= 10 which is not equal to 24.

Comment: I don't see any "nested cases" in the "coffee + cigar + MI" model.  In that model the calculation is $(4)(4)(2) - (4-1) - (4-1) - (2-1) -1  = 24$.

Comment: Would Case and Controls not be nested in Cigarettes per day?

Comment: I gather from the table that "Cases and Controls" is the same as the variable `MI`, which is not nested in the `coffee + cigar + MI` model.